# Real time analytic for android

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

In my android app I have included Firebase Analytic API to track my app users and uses.
But Firebase doesn't update analytic data immediately.I read it takes around 4 hours to update data.

Is there any good alternates for real time analytic?
Also I want to see live users at any moment who are using my app.

ps. I haven't used Google Analytic ever.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase analytics has a realtime feature called Streamview:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en

Comment: Do you know how often the Streamview Timeline updates @faridghar? I'm trying it with a signed APK and sometimes, when I send events I sit and watch the D Streamview Tmeline for up to 40 mins and nothing comes through, then I uninstall the app and everything comes through at once. Other times, the events come through fairly quickly (within 10 seconds or so), Is this expected behaviour? I can't seem to find anything on this. DebugView works perfectly every time (nice and quick!) Thanks –

Comment: Firebase analytics sends its data in batches (to preserve battery). This sending occurs every hour **OR** when a user performs a conversion or when the user puts the app in the background (on iOS) or uninstalls the app (Android). This is why you see all events coming through when you uninstall the app (I assume you're using Android?). If you want **really** realtime data, then DebugView is your answer. Please accept my answer above if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: More info here (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html) and here (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).

Comment: .@faridghar thanks I can't accept your answer as I didn't ask the original question :)